# d3 map - After using blur filter, zoom does not work properly

Tags: dictionary, filter, d3.js, zooming, blur

I am using the blur effect on the d3 map as given here: http://geoexamples.blogspot.in/2014/01/d3-map-styling-tutorial-ii-giving-style.html?

But after using this method (because of how the data is loaded..using datum) my zoom functionality behaves randomly. Irrespective of where I click it zooms to the same point. Also, the animations have become very slow after using the filter.

Is there any other way to achieve blur? Or a solution to this problem?

Any help?

Thanks.
This is the code for the world creation in case when filtering is required (use of datum as per the code on the above site).

```
d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error, world) {
 g.insert("path")
  .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
  .attr("d", path);
g.insert("path")
  .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
  .attr("d", path)
  .append("path");

    g.selectAll("path")
    .on("click", click);})
```

This is the code used in case filtering is not required (No use of datum - maybe the datum is causing the issue)

```
d3.json("world-110m2.json", function(error,topology) {
            g.selectAll("path")
                .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
                .geometries)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d",path)
                .on("click", click);)}
```

This is the zoom function: got the code from here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206590

```
function click(d) {

var x, y, k;
var centered;
if (d && centered !== d) {
var centroid = path.centroid(d);
x = centroid[0];
y = centroid[1];
k = 4;
centered = d;
} else {
x = width / 2;
y = height / 2;
k = 1;
centered = null;
}
if (active === d) return reset();
          g.selectAll(".active").classed("active", false);
          d3.select(this).classed("active", active = d);
          var b = path.bounds(d);

          g.selectAll("path")
              .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d    === centered; });

          g.transition()
              .duration(750)
              .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
              .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");

}
```

Comment: Could you post your complete code? There's no reason the zoom behaviour should behave differently with a filter.

Comment: I updated the code. When filtering is required, use of datum is required. Even when i dont end up applying the filter, the zoom doesnt work fine. Its somehow related to how I am using datum then.

Comment: You've posted two pieces of code that do the same thing, but haven't told us in which context they are used. It would also be helpful to see the zoom function.

Comment: I posted the two pieces of code to show the code difference. One is the code when filter is not required . The other code is the approach needed when we want to use filters.

Comment: Ah right, in the second case you're actually adding only a single object, that's why it zooms always to the same position. If you change the code that adds the paths to be like the code in the other case, it should work fine.

Comment: it works fine in the second case but doesn't work fine in the first case (where datum is used)

Comment: Sorry -- first -> no filter (`.data()` used), second -> filter (`.datum()` used). If you use `.data()` like in the no-filter example, it should work fine.

Comment: Yes that's true. But I cant seem to find a way to apply the filter affect to the continent boundaries without using datum. So it is either filter + datum or no filter + data.

Answer (score 0):

The blur filter consumes lots of resources, as indicated in the post. Speciallly if you combine it with other filters.

One solution would be using Canvas instead of SVG. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) you have some filters using the Canvas element. It should be possible to achieve the same result.

I can't find why the zoom stops working, but the performance is slower because you use all the data, so you are applying the filter to all the data instead of using only the part of the word you are showing, so you are using a much bigger image when you zoom.